# Simple pass-through AudioNode in Web Audio API?

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio-api

Using the [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API), I'd wish to connect an external [AudioNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioNode) to an encapsulated subsystem composed of an arbitrary, dynamically changeable chain of internal [AudioNodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioNode) - and as such, I need a node serving as a fixated entry point.

The relation between the external node and the subsystem can be presented with a very simple listing of [AudioNodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioNode) (each subsequent node below each other connect from top to bottom, the aforementioned subsystem is prefixed with a dash):

```
externalNode
 - input
 - effectNode1
 - effectNode2
 - effectNode3
 - outnode
externalNode
destination
```

But there is no such thing as a simple pass-through node in the [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API). How would I overcome this issue if I'd wish to keep good performance? I'm currently using a simple [GainNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GainNode) with its `gain.value` set to `1` so that it does not affect the output, but the setup still implies extra processing work.

Another possible setup could be using the [AnalyserNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode), which leaves the audio itself unchanged, but I'm unsure about its performance, or how I might be able to measure that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no pass-through node in WebAudio. I would use a GainNode as you're doing now. It can obviously be optimized to do no processing if the gain value is 1.  I would also submit that if the GainNode that you're adding is a significant fraction of the processing of your external node, then you're not doing anything interesting in the external node.

Comment: I'd additionally point out that I would *NOT* use an AnalyserNode; I'm pretty sure it would have far worse impact in terms of perf.